# crop image in amazon kindle devices by using crop intent

Tags: android, image, android-intent, kindle-fire

I'm trying to crop Imageview. In all devices image crop by using crop intent is working fine but not working for amazon kindle devices.

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");       
intent.setType("image/*");
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);
intent.putExtra("scaleType", "centerCrop");
intent.putExtra("crop", "true");
intent.putExtra("outputX", 1200);
intent.putExtra("outputY", 1600);
intent.putExtra("aspectX", 0);
intent.putExtra("aspectY", 0);
intent.putExtra("scale", true);
startActivityForResult(i, CROP_FROM_CAMERA);
```

is there any way to do that. Because crop inent is not supported by kindle.

Comment: Try to use some custom library for croping : https://github.com/edmodo/cropper or https://github.com/jdamcd/android-crop

Comment: You could always crop the image yourself.

Comment: @JoxTraex yes, we can crop the image by our self but i want custom cropper where i could  change the dimensions of cropper according to my will just like android camera cropper.

Comment: @HareshChhelana both are in gradle. can you please give me any other link.

Comment: Another thing is if the crop activity is not available, you could always just add it to your application too. Try reading the source code to find out the default handler or just use a 3p library.

Comment: @HareshChhelana Thank you dude, it is working, answer this question so that i can accept it as correct one. plus one for help  :)

Comment: Glad to help you,please check ans i have posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use some custom library for croping :

1. https://github.com/edmodo/cropper
2. https://github.com/jdamcd/android-crop